# How to adjust text UIDatePicker View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

How to adjust UIDatePicker adjust the text based on the screen size.
for iPhone 5s its not showing complete text for me.
Need to set font for UIDatePicker component.[image]

if you see the image september Novermber long text is not visible properly, and also Year 2018.....

Comment: `UIDatePicker` is not customizable. You would need to use the more generic `UIPickerView` to allow width adjustment.

Comment: @particleman Thats correct!  here on one view i used two DatePicker trying to display date and time!  If i adjust font size that makes good enough for me to fix the issue.